# How do i get the position of a URL in an array?

Tags: android, arrays, url, gridview

What I'm trying to achieve is to obtain the URL received from Instagram and pass its array position to an onlick listener for each corresponding photo in a grid view.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private InstagramSession mInstagramSession;
private Instagram mInstagram;

private ProgressBar mLoadingPb;
private GridView mGridView;

private static final String CLIENT_ID = "83549f9eb76f4a5b90daf6e4e14da107";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "6df26b0c8f664323a07126bfe8511651";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://www.yahoo.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mInstagram          = new Instagram(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

    mInstagramSession   = mInstagram.getSession();

    if (mInstagramSession.isActive()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        InstagramUser instagramUser = mInstagramSession.getUser();

        mLoadingPb  = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);
        mGridView   = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(instagramUser.fullName);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_username)).setText(instagramUser.username);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mInstagramSession.reset();

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageView userIv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_user);

        DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_user)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(false)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .writeDebugLogs()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)
                .build();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        AnimateFirstDisplayListener animate  = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        imageLoader.displayImage(instagramUser.profilPicture, userIv, animate);

        new DownloadTask().execute();

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mInstagram.authorize(mAuthListener);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private Instagram.InstagramAuthListener mAuthListener = new Instagram.InstagramAuthListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstagramUser user) {
        finish();

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String error) {
        showToast(error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("OK. Maybe later?");

    }
};

public static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}



ArrayList<String> photoList;



public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    protected void onCancelled() {

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        long result = 0;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "20"));

            InstagramRequest request = new InstagramRequest(mInstagramSession.getAccessToken());
            String response          = request.createRequest("GET", "/users/21846697/media/recent", params);

            if (!response.equals("")) {
                JSONObject jsonObj  = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                JSONArray jsonData  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                int length = jsonData.length();

                if (length > 0) {
                    photoList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPhoto = jsonData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("standard_resolution");

                        photoList.add(jsonPhoto.getString("url"));

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (photoList == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Photos Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            int width   = (int) Math.ceil((double) dm.widthPixels / 2);
            width=width-50;
            int height  = width;

            PhotoListAdapter adapter = new PhotoListAdapter(MainActivity.this);

            adapter.setData(photoList);
            adapter.setLayoutParam(width, height);

           mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                          int position, long id) {
                      // Maybe you'll have to cast it to a string, I'm currently writing directly in SO
                      String url = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                      Intent myintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullscreenImageView.class).putExtra("SelectedImageURL", position);
                      startActivity(myintent);
                  }
              });

            mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
}
}
```

PhotoListAdapter.java

```
public class PhotoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private AnimateFirstDisplayListener mAnimator;

private ArrayList<String> mPhotoList;

private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;

public PhotoListAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;

    DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.instagram_logo)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.instagram_logo)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.instagram_logo)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(false)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)
            .build();

    mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    mImageLoader.init(config);

    mAnimator  = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
}

public void setData(ArrayList<String> data) {
    mPhotoList = data;
}

public void setLayoutParam(int width, int height) {
    mWidth  = width;
    mHeight = height;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (mPhotoList == null) ? 0 : mPhotoList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageIv;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageIv = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageIv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mWidth, mHeight));
        imageIv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageIv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageIv = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    mImageLoader.displayImage(mPhotoList.get(position), imageIv, mAnimator);

    return imageIv;
}
}
```

FullScreenImageView.java

```
        import android.app.Activity;

public class FullscreenImageView extends Activity {

String imageURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedImageURL");

}
```

Comment: You removed a whole thread in which i already exactly told you how to do all. Now you are opening a new thread with the same code. What are you up to?

Comment: Well you just kept asking me questions without helping me, I'm just a beginner trying a few things out I just want a straight answer

Comment: There was no reason to remove that thread. I spend a lot of time helping you and you threw it all away. I gave you complete answer how to solve your problem so don't try to tell a different story. I repeat: it is strange that someone who wrote all this code is unable to pass an url by intent to another activity. Although him was explained how to get the url from a list and how to put that in putExtra.

Comment: Like I said I'm a beginner and I'm just trying a few things for my own education, I followed a tutorial to retrieve the data and parse it. Now I'm just curious how far I can take it and learn along the way

Answer (score 1):

The workflow of the gridView as you understood is to have an adapter to populate this view.

What I would do is that the getItem(int position) returns the URL which, if I good understood, is contained in your mPhotoList. Something like:

```
  @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mPhotoList.get(position);
}
```

And use it where you need it like this:

```
@Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Maybe you'll have to cast it to a string, I'm currently writing directly in SO
                String url = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
                Intent myintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullscreenImageView.class).putExtra("SelectedImageURL", url);
                startActivity(myintent);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi so thank you for the swift response however, it cannot resolve the symbol getAdapter?

Comment: Sorry, yeah not getAdapter but getAdapter()... I edited the answer.

Comment: ahhh its okay i shouldvenoticed that too. However it still stops the app from running when i click and shows "  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.londatiga.android.example/net.londatiga.android.example.FullscreenImageView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" in the LOGCAT

Comment: Ok, normal because you're adding the position and not the URL so copy the code that I edited and then, set a breakpoint at the line starting by "Intent myintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,..." and tell me the value of the url variable when you click on an image.

Comment: hey so i replaced the code so it says url instead of position and it still hits the same error when i click

Comment: Ok then the matter is in the FullScreen activity, post your FullScreen code in order that I can verify it (just edit your question and add your code).

Comment: Update: fullscreen activity has been added to the original code

Comment: Ok, what happens if you put this getintent.getStringExtra in the onCreate method ?

Comment: so i put String imageURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedImageURL");inside an on create method and when i click on an image the new activity launches all fine but it is simple blank with no image. side note in fullscreen activity it tells me the variable URL is never used?

Comment: Yeah and he is right the variable is never used because you do not do anything with your image URL; you've to create an Image which takes the whole screen, to get the picture from the URL and to apply this picture to the full screen image view. But your problem with the URL is solved :) (make another question of you can't find what you need on the internet)